# Create new row in Pandas DataFrame based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to iterate over every row in the dataframe and create another row if it matches certain criteria. For example

```
       A                 B           C
       Both             999          LP
       London           1002         KI
       Manchester       1005         BV
       Both             1001         IG
```

Will result in:

```
       A                 B                   C
       Both             999                  LP
       Both             (Some calculation)   LP
       London           1002                 KI
       Manchester       1005                 BV
       Both             1001                 IG
```

We look at every row and if column A equals "Both" and B is less than 1000, insert a new row where col A stays the same, col B is based on a function I have written and col C stays the same.

```
def create_new_row(row):
    if row['A'] == "Both":
        if row['B'] < 1000:
             result = somefuction(row['B'])

    return result
```

This is the code I have so far but I can't work out how to get the dataframe I want.

Comment: You can replace the last if with a *and*.

Comment: Otherwise what's the value of the new column? A null?

Comment: if the place where you insert the new line is not important, filter the dataframe to get the rows that satisfy your condition, generate the new lines based on the filtered database, join the result with the original dataframe

Comment: @MarcoP - Exactly you are right

Answer (score 3):

Filter the dataframe to get the rows that satisfy your condition by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = (df['A'] == "Both") & (df['B'] < 1000)
df1 = df[m].copy()
```

Generate the new lines based on the filtered database:

```
#sample function
def somefuction(x):
    return x / 100

df1['B'] = df1['B'].apply(somefuction)
```

Join the result with the original dataframe by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and sorting for correct order by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), last create default index by `reset_index`:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
            A        B   C
0        Both   999.00  LP
1        Both     9.99  LP
2      London  1002.00  KI
3  Manchester  1005.00  BV
4        Both  1001.00  IG
```