# function to generate new records based on conditions in a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, function, newline

can someone help me, an idea to create a function which evaluates two dates and generates new records with daily breaks:

initial data frame

```
d = {'name': ['Jack','James'], 'Date_ini': ['2022/01/20 10:10:25','2022/01/22 10:10:25']  ,'Date_end':['2022/01/24 20:24:15','2022/01/22 12:10:25']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

| name | Date_ini | Date_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 2022-01-20 10:10:25 | 2022-01-24 20:24:15 |
| James | 2022-01-22 10:10:25 | 2022-01-22 12:10:25 |

I would like to have the following output

| name | Date_ini | Date_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 2022-01-20 10:10:25 | 2022-01-20 23:59:59 |
| Jack | 2022-01-21 00:00:00 | 2022-01-21 23:59:59 |
| Jack | 2022-01-22 00:00:00 | 2022-01-22 23:59:59 |
| Jack | 2022-01-23 00:00:00 | 2022-01-23 23:59:59 |
| Jack | 2022-01-24 00:00:00 | 2022-01-24 20:24:15 |
| James | 2022-01-22 10:10:25 | 2022-01-22 12:10:25 |

Comment: hi, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475811/create-new-row-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-conditions

Comment: I think https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html or possibly https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html will be helpful here. Great job on the simple, minimal reproduceable example btw.